# Error in parsing JSON data properly using Go

Tags: json, string, parsing, csv, go

I'm a newbie to Go and trying use a library from github to parse JSON to CSV. https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv

But i encountered this issue: https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv/issues/22 to which the author is not replying.

I realized that if we give following JSON as json.input to the file:

```
{"user": {"name":["jehiah, mike, semo"], "password": "root"}, "remote_ip": "127.0.0.1", "dt" : "[20/Aug/2010:01:12:44 -0400]"}
{"user": {"name":["jeroenjanssens", "jeroen2", "jero55"], "password": "123"}, "remote_ip": "192.168.0.1", "dt" : "[20/Aug/2010:01:12:44 -0400]"}
{"user": {"name":"markdata", "password": ""}, "remote_ip": "76.216.210.0", "dt" : "[20/Aug/2010:01:12:45 -0400]"}
```

Now if i try using it as command: `go run main.go -k user.name -i input.json -o output.json`

it returns following output:

```
"[jehiah, mike, semo]"
[jeroenjanssens jeroen2 jero55]
markdata
```

but as described in opend issued, i'm expecting the response as:

```
jehiah, mike, semo
jeroenjanssens, jeroen2, jero55
markdata
```

i'm guessing it is happening due to line: https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv/blob/master/main.go#L110 which is anyhow removing commas while reading the line.

Can you please advice to how to achieve above desired output?

Regards

Comment: Why don't you just serialize the data read from the json file without using any other library? Have you got specific requirements?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia how do i do that? any example?

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope that will help you with your task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code you will be able to read your json data in a Go struct really easily:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// define the User type 
type User struct {
    Name     []string
    Password string
}

type DataStruct struct {
    User      User
    Remote_ip string
    Dt        string
}

func main() {
     var jsonBlob = []byte(`{"user": {"name":["jehiah, mike, semo"], "password": "root"},
  "remote_ip": "127.0.0.1", "dt" : "[20/Aug/2010:01:12:44 -0400]"}`)

     var data DataStruct
     err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &data)
     if err != nil {
          fmt.Println("error:", err)
     } else {
          fmt.Printf("%+v", data)
     }

}
```

If you have never used the *encoding/json* package you should read the official [Golang json article](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

When you have correctly read the data in the *DataStruct* structure, you will be able to serialize it using the proper [Golang csv package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues at play here:

1. The structures defined by JSON are not all representable in CSV, for example:

   - Objects e.g. `{"name":"john"}`
   - Arrays e.g. `["john", "mike", "sam"]`
2. There is no CSV standard. Well, there is RFC-4180, but most CSV encoders/decoders don't adhere to it because Microsoft.
3. The package you are using is very poorly coded.

One of the main differences among CSV implementation is the quote-handling. Consider the JSON string: `"\"Hello, world!\""`.

Depending on our marshaller we could end up with any of the following CSV representations for the string:

- `"""Hello, world!"""`
- `"\"Hello, world!\""`
- `'"Hello, world!"'`

Some encoders will even escape the comma inside of the string. The package you describe circumvents this issue by skipping the commas altogether. Which is a very poor design decision if you ask me.

Everything you need is in Go's standard library:

1. [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)
2. [`encoding/csv`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/)